# Access variable in Dlg class from App class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, combobox

I am writing a Dialog Based C++ application with MFC for the GUI. After the creation of the project, Visual Studio also created two classes `ProjectNameApp` and `ProjectNameDlg`. When adding a Menu to my application the menu item handlers (for the menu buttons) are added as methods to the `ProjectNameApp` class. In one of these handlers I want to access a variable of the `ProjectNameDlg` class, more specific, a `CComboBox`. But that, of course, is not possible. So I have two questions:

1. is there a way to acces that `CComboBox` variable from the Dlg class?
2. if not, how can I move the Menu handlers to the Dlg class to directly use the `CComboBox` variable?

Also, my application has to be dialog based, and it has to have a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last I dealt with any of this was in VS-2008, but if memory serves the CDialog object is probably allocated on the stack in CProjectNameApp::InitInstance().  There is probably some code there that looks kind of like:

```
CProjectNameDlg dlg;
int nResponse = dlg.DoModal();
```

One thing you could do is to add a pointer to the dialog as a member of the ProgramNameApp class. So in ProgramNameApp.h add a data element like:

```
std::tr1::unique_ptr<CProjectNameDlg> m_pDlg;
```

Then change the code in CProjectNameApp::InitInstance() to be:

```
m_pDlg = std::tr1::unique_ptr<CProjectNameDlg>(new CProjectNameDlg());
int nResponse = m_pDlg->DoModal();
```

Naturally you'd have to be on the lookout for any other uses of `dlg` and change them accordingly.